# How to use a loop to get user input?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

The purpose is to let the user to input a random amount of numbers and display these numbers on the screen. For example:

```
input: 12 34 45 12 3
output: 12 34 45 12 3
input: 2 4 100
output: 2 4 100
```

Here is my code:

```
section .text
GLOBAL main
EXTERN printf

section .data
integer: times 4 db 0     ;store the current data
num: times 4 db 0         ;store the current input character
count: times 4 db 0       ;count how many numbers
formatin: db "%d", 0      ; output format

main:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp                ;reserve the previous reg

  mov dword[integer], 1       ;set integer to 1
  mov dword[count], 0         ;set count to 0
read:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, num
  mov edx, 1
  int 80h                     ; read in a character

  cmp dword[num], 0Dh         ; if it' s an enter
  je done
  cmp dword[num], 20h         ; if it;s a space
  je nextNum

  sub dword[num], 30h         ;replace integer to 10*integer+num
  mov eax, dword[integer]
  imul eax, 10
  add eax, dword[num]
  mov dword[integer], eax
  loop read

nextNum:                       ; push integer to stack
  add dword[count], 1
  push integer
  mov dword[integer], 1
  loop read

done:
  mov ecx, dword[count]
write:                         ; print the result
  push formatin
  call printf
  add esp, 8
loop write
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret
```

The problem is that it gets stuck in the loop and it can't jump out of it. What's wrong?

The code:

```
cmp dword[num], 0Dh
```

and

```
cmp dword[num], 20h
```

Seem to have no effect. Maybe there is problem with `num`? Should I change it to a byte?

---

Since some suggest the declaration `dword[num]` may cause problem, I fix some of the code like this:

in `section .data`
change `num: times 4 db 0`  to  `num: times 1 db 0`

in all `dword[num]` 
change it to `byte[num]`,
but keep `add eax, dword[num]` as before

But it is still stuck in the loop...

---

Thanks to @Michael Petch   , I've found some logic problems and replace the `read` and `nextNum` segment with the following code:

```
read:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, num
  mov edx, 1
  int 80h                           ; read in a character

  cmp byte[num], 0Ah ; if it' s an enter
  je nextNum
  cmp byte[num], 20h ; if it;s a space
  je nextNum

  sub byte[num], 30h      ;replace integer to 10*integer+num
  mov eax, dword[integer]
  imul eax, 10
  add eax, dword[num]
  mov dword[integer], eax
  loop read

nextNum:                           
  add dword[count], 1
  push dword[integer]
  mov dword[integer], 0
  cmp byte[num], 0Ah
  je done
  cmp byte[num], 20h
  je  read
```

But it will now give unexpected answers. For example I give 12 34 , and it prints 2850, 12. Seems counting or data address calculating(which I still can not understand quite well ) go wrong

---

I've figured out what's wrong with the calculation. In fact, although `mov dword[integer], 0` in `nextNum` segment give value 0 to `integer`, `integer` will be 256 actually in the second loop, and be 512 in the third loop, and be 768... and so on. Can anyone explain why...

Comment: I tried to change the type of num to byte, but it is still trapped...

Comment: You want to continue until you read a newline character. If you are on Linux, then the newline is `0x0a` not `0x0d`.

Comment: Secondly, _ECX_ is a volatile register. It is caller saved and can be destroyed by a function you call. When you call `printf` in your wrote loop _ECX_ is trashed on every iteration. You should use a non-volatile register (callee saved) like _EBX_ for the loop. You'd need to remove `loop write` and replace it with `dec ebx` `jnz write` and change `mov ecx, dword[count]` to `mov ebx, dword[count]`

Comment: I just noticed you have this at the top `section .text` `GLOBAL main`
`EXTERN printf` . You then define a .data section and then you add your code to the data section. You should move those 3 lines **after** your .text section. just before the start of your code.

Comment: @Michael Petch    it works! But the output is wrong...

Comment: Your going to have to work on your logic. You don't save the number on the stack when the person hits enter. A space is the end of a number and so is the enter key. When someone hits enter your code will have to push that number on the stack. Which brings me to one other bug - I think you mean to do `push dword[integer]` not `push integer`

Comment: @Michael Petch  I fixed some logic problems and it's nearly finished. If I input `12 34 56`,  it will print `5688 2850 12`

Comment: You really should change `loop read` to `jmp read` . I'm not entirely sure you understand that `loop read` uses the value in _ECX_ to branch. `jmp read` would not be conditional on anything.

Comment: If you are in fact using that updated code you posted, I hope you changed `mov dword[integer], 1` `mov dword[count], 0` to `mov dword[integer], 0` `mov dword[count], 0`

Comment: @Michael Petch Many thanks, All problems solved